# ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import and Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just started demo program in python using tensor.
I am a beginner at python.
I executed the command :

> python ./getStartWithTensor.py

But the output is like 
[commandline screenshot of tensor program execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPGcF.png)

Here is code I have written :

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W*x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})

# evaluate training accuracy
curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

How can I resolve it? I am new to python and tensorflow.
Thanks.

Comment: I could not find `getStartWithTensor.py` online so I assume it is a file you created? Please provide a MWE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve from your `getStartWithTensor.py` which causes the error.

Comment: @MrZ ,  I created that file, got reference from : https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started#complete_program